# Aufs mount alternative

Tags: terminal, mount

What union mounts are available on OSX? I've been using [Aufs](http://aufs.sourceforge.net) on Ubuntu for the past few years without fail and I'm looking for something similar...

Basically, given n directories, merge the contents into another directory in real-time. Any changes to the mount directory does not affect the original paths, and the changes that were made are put into the furthest left path. This allows me to create a complex working directory of several repositories, while maintaining the history and integrity of those directories cleanly.

Example:

```
mount -t aufs -o br=/src1:/src2:/src3 none /path/to/stacked/dir
```

Would combine `src1, src2` and `src3` into `/path/to/stacked/dir`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `union` option available in OSX's `mount`:

`sudo mount -t hfs -o union /dev/disk9s1 /tmp/union`

See also: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20181226172725/http://osxbook.com/book/bonus/ancient/whatismacosx/arch_fs.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any equivalent file system for Mac OS X.

The closest offering is the [OSXFuse](http://osxfuse.github.io) project, where developers can implement custom file systems in user space. OSXFuse mentions the following file systems, none of which rival [aufs](http://aufs.sourceforge.net/)'s capabilities:

- sshfs
- procfs
- AccessibilityFS
- GrabFS
- LoopbackFS
- SpotlightFS
- YouTubeFS